# cannot able to get file name from azure blob container

Tags: azure, c#-4.0

I have one azure container which is public to all and i want to retrieve filename present in that public container.

Here is My code.

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureWebJobsStorage"].ToString());

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(sourceurl);  //my path from where i have to get filename  

//here i got 400 bad request error.
var blobs = container.ListBlobs(null, true, BlobListingDetails.All).Cast<CloudBlockBlob>().ToList();   
foreach (var blockBlob in blobs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + blockBlob.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Size: " + blockBlob.Properties.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Content type: " + blockBlob.Properties.ContentType);
    Console.WriteLine("Download location: " + blockBlob.Uri);
    Console.WriteLine("=======================================");
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `sourceurl`?

Comment: sourceurl is my complete container address from where i want to access my file. for ex: "vcmobilesiteiislogs/VCMOBILESITE/2015/07/10/10/"

Comment: So you container name is `vcmobilesiteiislogs` and you want to fetch files from `VCMOBILESITE/2015/07/10/10/` folder in there. Correct?

Comment: yes you are right ,but i want the file which is present in the subfolders of vcmobilesiteiislogs ,how can i access them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, please change your code to something like the following:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("vcmobilesiteiislogs");
var blobs = container.ListBlobs("VCMOBILESITE/2015/07/10/10/", true, BlobListingDetails.All).Cast<CloudBlockBlob>().ToList();
```

Essentially `vcmobilesiteiislogs` is your container and you want to fetch blobs names of which start with `VCMOBILESITE/2015/07/10/10/` (or in other words in that sub folder though I must state that blob storage does not have a concept of folders. You just create an illusion of folder hierarchy by prefixing the blob with some name that you want to use as a folder name).

So you would pass `VCMOBILESITE/2015/07/10/10/` as blob prefix when you call [`ListBlobs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs.aspx) method on your container.